# htaccess rewrite part of url and leave rest as it is

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite part of my url as a parameter and part as a path. Is it possible and if so can anyone please help me

To be more specific I have an url like this:

```
www.mysite/products/producer:some+producer/category:some+category/color:red,blue,yellow
```

and what I need is

```
www.mysite/products.php/producer:some+producer/category:some+category/color:red,blue,yellow
```

To make things more interesting depending on user query path after `www.mysite/products/` can by shorter or longer

If I had constant number of parameters I would write something like that

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/?$ products.php/$1/$2 [L]
```

but as a number of parameters changes I have no idea what to do

That's my whole htaccess so far

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.pl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.pl/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)/?$ /products.php/$1 [NE,L]

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method #1 just changes products and keeps everything else the same

```
RewriteRule ^products/$ products.php [NC,L,B,QSA]
```

Method #2

```
RewriteRule ^products/producer:(.*)/category:(.*)/color:(.*)$ products.php?producer=$1&category=$2&color=$3 [NC,L]
```

And here's probably what your htaccess file should look like.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Prevents directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP

# your 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/your/404file.php

RewriteRule ^products/$ products.php [NC,L,B,QSA]
```

Comment: although your first method looks promising all it gives me is 404 error

Comment: @krzysztof make sure you have `Options -MultiViews` enabled

Comment: yes I have right option enabled and I could even say that your second method is working - one problem it requires to handle every scenario in htaccess and I was looking for something more universal as I am much better in php.

Comment: @krzysztof if this `www.mysite/products/producer:some+producer/category:some+category/color:red,blue,yellow` is your exact URL it will not work. You will need change it to something like `www.mysite/products/?producer=foo&category=foo&color=foo`

Comment: @krzysztof basically method#1 will only change products to products.php. Everything else will stay the same

Comment: @krzysztof can you paste the link you're getting 404 for?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like there is error or purposeful misconfiguration at hosting company level. Although it's not exactly what I was hoping for I will go with your second method and I am marking your answer as acceptable

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `.+` check:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)/?$ /products.php/$1 [NE,L]
```

---

Putting the floating directives in their respective module checks:

```
Options -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.pl
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.pl/$1 [R=permanent,L]
    RewriteRule ^products/(.+)/?$ /products.php/$1 [NE,L]
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_filters.c>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: it gives me Internal Server Error

Comment: @krzysztof Sorry, I missed the leading `/` there. Check now

Comment: still the same result

Comment: @krzysztof Can you confirm whether `Options -MultiViews` is there in your htaccess? Also, please check the server's error logs.

Comment: it seems i don't have access to error logs or there are none (from my perspective directory is empty). I've posted my whole htaccess above

Comment: @krzysztof It could've because of uninitialised modules. Update the htaccess with the one in my edit above.

Comment: unfortunately same effect

Comment: @krzysztof You'd need to look for errors in the PHP code. The htaccess above is working on my local machine. If you can ask the hosting company, as for the error logs, and check what issue is actually there.

Comment: at the moment my php code is print_r($_GET) as I am testing Trevor Wood solution.
Thank you for your help. It looks like there is error or purposeful misconfiguration at hosting company level.